# Let $f:\Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R} $ a continuous function s.t. $f(x+y)+f (x-y)=2f(x)+2f(y) $. Find $f$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, functional-equations

Let $f:\Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R} $ a continuous function s.t. $f(x+y)+f (x-y)=2f(x)+2f(y) $. Find $f$.

My idea: Let $x=y$. Then $f (2x)+f(0)=4f(x)$. I tried to use this recurrence but it doesn't work.

Comment: Let $x = y = 0$, $f(0)+f(0) = 4f(0)$, so $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: $f(x)=x^2$ is a solution.

Comment: Now i would try $$f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$$

Comment: i think it is $$f(x)=ax^2$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As already noted in the comments, $f(0)=0$ (take $x=y=0$), and $f(-z)=f(z)$ (take $x=0$, $y=z$). Further, $f(az)=a^2 f(z)$ for natural $a$ (it is proven by induction on $a$ taking $x=az$, $y=z$), and therefore for any rational $a$ (because $f(z)=f(az)/a^2$). By continuity, it holds for any real $a$.

So $f(x)=x^2 f(1)$.

Answer (score 2):

As I'm new I can't comment but here is something you should consider:

Let $x=0\ ,\ f(y)+f(-y)=2f(y)\ , so\ f(-y)=f(y)$

Also I proved for integers:

Let $x=k-1\ ,y=1 : f(k)+f(k-2)=2f(k-1)+2f(1)$

Now let $k=0 : f(0)+f(2)=2f(1)+2f(1)\Leftrightarrow f(2)=4f(1)$

If for every integer $0\le l \le k$ we have $f(l)=l^2f(1)$ then:

$f(k+1)+f(k-1)=2f(k)+2f(1)\Leftrightarrow
f(k+1)+(k-1)^2f(1)=2k^2f(1)+2f(1)\Leftrightarrow
f(k+1)=f(1)(2k^2+2-(k-1)^2)\\ \qquad \qquad \; \ \ 
=f(1)(2k^2+2 -(k^2-2k+1))\\ \qquad \qquad \; \ \ 
=f(1)(k^2+2k+1)\\ \qquad \qquad \; \ \ 
=(k+1)^2f(1)$

Therefore by induction we get $f(x)=x^2f(1)$

Comment: Please, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) (i.e. LaTeX commands) fot mathematical notations.